# Route to IP:PORT instead of interface - translate 10.20.30.40:443 -> 127.0.0.1:1443

Tags: windows, routes, proxy, masquerade

I have (banyan) tunnel to some service, it is listening on `127.0.0.1:1443`
But previously I had VPN and was able to connect directly to `IP:PORT`, like `10.20.30.40:443`
The problem is, I need to be able to connect to `10.20.30.40:443` (the tool is not offering `IP:PORT` change).
I was thinking about routing, but classic `route add` accepts only interface.
What I need is translation `10.20.30.40:443 -> 127.0.0.1:1443`
Since `10.*` is a local address I need to create manual route to some interface. And something needs to listen on this interface and `translate incoming IP:PORT to outgoing IP:PORT`.

It is for Windows, but I guess in the worst case, I can install some light Linux distribution in VM with banyan and tunnel it through there.

I'm thinking about using `badvpn-tun2socks`, route to `10.*` to badvpn `TUN` adapter. But I need some local socks server which will do the `translation between input IP:PORT and output IP:PORT`. Is there anything like that?
Or is there any other approach?
I tried

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=443 listenaddress=10.20.30.40 connectport=1443 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

But I cannot make it work. I tried to add route for `10.20.30.40` to local adapter, but didn't work. I is probably wrong approach anyway.